# Complement of Pandas Dataframe Sample

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

sample = df.sample(10)

sample.to_csv("train_subset.csv")
```

I want to sample 10 random rows from a given csv file (train.csv) and store it as a new csv file train_subset.csv.
The code above achieves that. Now I also want to store all the rows that weren't sampled into a file train_remaining.csv.

How can I implement that? How do I find which rows were sampled?

Comment: Look at [SciKit Learn train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`df.index.difference(sample.index)`

where sample.index is the sected sample index.

And then use it for select the complementary dataframe:

`complementary = df.iloc[df.index.difference(sample.index)]`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using sklearns train_test_split.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

This will allow you to take a percentage of the rows that are randomly selected.

Comment: Could you kindly show me more explicitly how to use this? I am confused by the documentation. @Greg

Comment: 'import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

X = df['features_used_to_predict']
y = df['thing_being_predicted']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)'

If you want you can concat the test info to get a subset of the data.